# How could i pass jwt token from back end nodejs to front end angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I create a jwt token and stored in database. when login successfully done i want to redirect to home page with token. how could i do that.

My Nodejs file.

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({name: req.body.name}, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {throw err;}

        if (!user) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        } else if (user) {

          // check if password matches
          if (user.password !==  req.body.password) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
          } else {

            // if user is found and password is right
            // create a token
            var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
              expiresIn: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
            });

            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Enjoy your token!',
              token: token
            });
          }   

        }

      });
    });
```

My angularjs file

```
var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);
  // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
  app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.user = {};
    // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      // Posting data to  file
      $http.post('/tokken/login/', $scope.user).then(function (response) {
          //$http.defaults.headers.common['Token'] = token
        if (response.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorName = response.errors.name;
          $scope.erroPassword = response.errors.password;
        } else {
          $scope.message = response.data;
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

I print token value in same login page. I want to redirect to another page with the token

Comment: Have you tried this : res.redirect('/homepage?token=' + token);

Comment: How do you call authenticate function from angular, from form post or ajax

Comment: added my angularjs